# Cocoa - Filter an Array NSDictionary on a tableview

Tags: cocoa, search, nsdictionary, nstableview

I've a tableview that has an array of dictionaries datasource. Now I want to do a filter inside this table, but I want to be able to filter for 5 different fields, like name, number, email, etc.

How can I do it? I've found a way to do it in a Array, but I can't figure how to make it on a dicionary.

Comment: Is your table view populated with just one dictionary, or are you talking about an array of dictionaries?

Comment: Is an Array of Dictionaries. I updated the question.

Comment: Ok. Now, what do you mean by "search"? Do you want to find a specific result, or are you trying to filter the array, to present a subset in your table view?

Comment: Filter. Seems that I explained my self really badly. Sorry for that, I will reedit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter an array of dictionaries, just use filteredArrayUsingPredicate: something like this:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name = %@",@"Fabio"];
NSArray *filtered = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

This will give you an array where all the dictionaries will have the name value of Fabio.

After Edit: if you want to do a broader search you could add an "OR" in the predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name = %@ OR SELF.email BEGINSWITH[c] %@",@"Fabio",@"fabio"];
```

This would give you any dictionaries where the name is Fabio, or the email starts with fabio (or Fabio, the [c] parameter means it will match either capitalized or not).

Comment: Humm, and that gives me the index of the array, a nsdictionary, where that string is? Like if I have several dictionaries on a array, and each one has like name, email, number, no matter if I put fabio, or fabio@email.com or my number, that array will give me that and show it on the table?

Comment: No, it doesn't give you an index -- it gives you a new array which only has dictionaries where the name field is Fabio. And, no, it won't give you any dictionaries where the email is fabio@email.com, only ones where the name is fabio. If you want to do a broader search you can do it like I show in my edited answer.

Comment: Awesome man! You saved my day. I will try it now, and I will get back to you. I came from front-end so there are some things, that are hard to me to do. And thanks to this community, I'm hable to do my work. Thanks a lot rdelmar!

Comment: Works just fine! You saved my day rdermar!

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSPredicateFilter` based on which column you clicked.